# How to replace the white blanks with four in vim?

Tags: vim

There are 5 white blanks in line 3,6 white blanks in line 4,7 white blanks in line 5.
I want to replace them with 4 white blanks,how to write the command?

It is not `%3,7s/^\s*/    /g` ,how to fix it?

```
    it is a test
     it is a test
      it is a test
```

I want change it into:

```
   it is a test
   it is a test
   it is a test
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You typed `:%3,7s/^\s*/    /g`, but `%` is a range and `3,7` is another range, so it's wrong : you have to choose between them:

```
:%s ...
```

will replace in the whole file, or

```
:3,7s ...
```

will only replace in lines from 3 to 7.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your example, it sounds like you want to replace all sequences of whitespace at the beginning of lines with 4 spaces.

Please comment if I have misinterpreted your question. You can do this by looking for an arbitrary amount of whitespace at the beginning of line and replacing with four spaces.

```
%s/^\s\+/    /g
```